# No pedal resistance in the clutch - 1998 Ford Ranger

Tags: ford, clutch

i let someone use my truck that apparently did not no how to drive a stick and limped it home in 2nd gear by turning it off putting it in gear.

Now there is no pedal resistance but with the clutch pressed it does release/engage the gear and allow the vehicle to start and take off while turning the key but it is hard to get out of the gear without pressing in the clutch even though it feels like there isn't one and WILL NOT GO INTO GEAR NO MATER HOW HARD I TRY ONE OUT OF THE GEAR I TOOK OFF IN

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying.  Can you simplify the issues into bullet points? Can you please add some data and clarify your verbiage as well?  That would really help.  Welcome to the site!  Cheers!

Comment: Please be more specific in the problems you are experiencing, and please do not type in ALL CAPS as this can be percieved as shouting.  Describe the shift problems you are having.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves me correctly the Ford Ranger is a hydraulic clutch. First thing I would check is fluid leaks the clutch master and slave cylinders as well as the lines that interconnect the two. Second check if there is any fluid in the cylinder. Low fluid could introduce air in the line and that could cause issues.